# Could not create parent directory for lock file android studio

Tags: gradle, radiance-flamingo

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naqRJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naqRJ.png)

I'm using android studio flamingo. If I open any android studio project I'm facing the above error.
[Gradle Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWgXK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWgXK.png)

I tried changing the gradle version in project settings and also tried changing gradle JDK but none of them didn't work